# SQL insert foreign key if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, json, duplicates, sql-insert

Suppose I have a table `user`:

```
PK id: int
firstname: varchar
lastname: varchar
FK group_id: int
```

And a table `group`:

```
PK id: int
name: varchar
```

Now I want to be able to send to the server a student JSON object that contains:

```
{
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "doe",
    "group": "group_name"
}
```

How to insert it in the tables? How can I ensure that a row with "group_name" exists and if not, create it and then and only then insert the student with the corresponding FK group_id?

What I would do is something like:

1. select id from group where name="group_name"
2. if not exists:
   insert into group values ("group_name")
3. insert into user values("john", "doe", the_existing_or_newly_inserted_group_id)

But it seems a bit overkill in terms of number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do this with just two statements:

```
insert into groups (group_name) 
select s.group_name
from (select :group_name as group_name) s
where not exists (select 1 from groups g where g.group_name = s.group_name);

insert into users (firstname, lastname, group_id)
select :firstname, :lastname, g.group_id
from groups g
where g.group_name = :group_name;
```

The first statement create the new group if it does not yet exists. The second statement recovers the id of the group and inserts the user information.

For this to properly work, `group_name` must be a unique key in the `groups` table.

Notes:

- You might want to wrap the statements in a single transaction so concurrency is properly managed
- Values preceded by `:` represents the parameters of the queries, that should be passed from the application
- *Both* `user` and `group` are language keywords, hence poor choices for object names; I changed the table names to `users` and `groups`.

Comment: If `group_name` is defined as unique (but it must!) then `insert ignore into groups` is more simple and useful (and does not need in WHERE).

Comment: @Akina: yes, or `on duplicate key`... But I was trying not to burn sequence numbers, so `not exists`.